# how to Invoke fragment and send data together?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

How to invoke fragment and send data together in android fragment framework?

Basically i want to type text from fragment1 and send text to fragment2, But together on button click in fragment1 i want to invoke fragment2 and display text
that i typed in editext in fragment1 at same time.
below are codes:-
fragement1---

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,container,false);
    final EditText edittext= rootview.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Button button= rootview.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            anInterface.interface1(edittext.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "just test",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return rootview;
}
```

MainActivity:---

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    frag1= new Fragment1();
    fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction= fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_1,frag1);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
@Override
public void interface1(String string) {
    frag2 = new Fragment2();
    fragmentTransaction= fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_2,frag2);        
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    frag2.textv(string);
   }
```

fragment2:---

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2,container,false);
    textView= rootview.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    return rootview;
}
public void textv(String string){
   textView.setText(string);
}
```

The error iam getting

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

As i searched layout to be attached before invoking textview method and i did it that in main activity code but no sucess

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_2,frag2);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    frag2.textv(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void interface1(String string) {
    frag2 = new Fragment2();
    fragmentTransaction= fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_2,frag2);        
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    frag2.textv(string);
   }
```

you try to access the frag2 views although it's not created yet ! so NPE will be thrown 
you have to send the value string into a bundle to the fragment2 
and in the onCreate of the fragment2 .. you read the value and update the ui .. 
or 
if you make sure that the fragment2 is already added and attached to the Activity then access its views.

Comment: yes actully i was calling textview.settext() out of oncreateview() method in fragment2 basically it need to be call in oncreateview() or oncreate() or onactivitycreated() method.